# How is HotelTonight doing their custom transitions?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, view, transition

In the HotelTonight app, they have very specific custom transitions between view controllers:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1d-ptlOPOCs

Is it possible to achieve this using the iOS 7 custom transition APIs? All of the demos I have seen so far of that API revolve around slides, folds, fades etc.

Comment: How are we meant to know how another developer has done their code?

Comment: You're not - I'll rephrase my question to "Is it possible to achieve this using the iOS 7 custom APIs?"

Comment: Yes this is completely possible, but the who is to broad to discus on stack overflow. You can have a custom animator for navigation controller and when presenting a view controller.

Comment: That is still a pretty vague question that could result in a YES/NO answer. You need to be attempting it yourself and when/if you fail come back and ask something along the lines of `"I am trying to achieve X. I have attempted to use the following code but have been unsuccesful (Highlight the code). blah blah blah..... "`

Comment: That would be a good route, but a YES/NO is all I really want at the moment. I'd have (previous to iOS 7), attempted this by manually moving UIView's, and fading in others, in some sort of container view controller.

Most of the iOS 7 Custom Transition tutorials reference simple animations that affect the entire view (for example, fading one view and bringing in another). In this case, individual elements need to be moved and, almost persist, between view controllers. 

I wasn't sure if the custom transition APIs were powerful enough for this functionality.

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't really for just YES/NO answers its for coding related issues.

Comment: @ChristopherKevinHowell You can select the view you want from the "fromViewController" and the "ToViewController" in your transition class. Then, you move one item by changing its frame to match the one in the "toViewController". In the meantime, you fade in/out the other controllers in the same transition class. One way is to take "snapshot", have a look at this example : http://code4app.net/ios/iOSSharedViewTransition/54057e39e24741931ff2ba2f , the transition class may help you understand how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.objc.io/issue-12/custom-container-view-controller-transitions.html

This tutorial gives a very nice introduction to custom transition APIs with sample. However, most tutorials will only provide samples for most basic transitions (slide, fade etc.). You will have to build the custom transition on your own based on information found in the above (and similar other) tutorials. The short answer is YES this is probably what that app is using (there is no way to be 100% sure) but you will probably not find a tutorial explaining exactly how to replicate it.

Some other resources:

http://possiblemobile.com/2013/09/ios-7-custom-transitions/

http://www.objc.io/issue-5/view-controller-transitions.html

The related WWDC session would be highly helpful as well